# Stop setInterval() function when using .hover()?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a setInterval() function that highlights one of 4 divs and then proceeds to the next one, the whole cycle repeats and takes 4 seconds to do so. But I want to make a function that would stop the setInterval() function once I hover on top of one of the divs and just highlight the div I'm hovering on. On leaving the div, the setInterval() function should start again.

HTML:

```
<div class="content color">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<div class="content ">
<p>Ola</p>
</div>

<div class="content ">
<p>Namaste</p>
</div>

<div class="content ">
<p>See Ya!</p>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
 function loopy(){
    var items  = $(" .content");
    var length = items.length;

    items.each(function(i, ele) {
        if ($(ele).hasClass("color")) {
            $(ele).animate({opacity: 0.5},500).removeClass("color");

            if (i < (length-1)) {

                $(items[i+1]).animate({  opacity: 1},500).addClass("color");

            }
            else {
                $(items[0]).animate({ opacity: 1},500).addClass("color");
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

function CF()
{
    window.setInterval(function(){loopy();},4000);
}

CF();
```

I created CF() as a function which contains the setInterval() function. I can't think of how I can stop CF() when I create a .hover() function on the "content" class. And once my mouse stops hovering on the "content" class , CF() should start again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this (Updated code)

```
var intervalId;

function loopy() {
    var items = $(" .content");
    var length = items.length;

    items.each(function(i, ele) {
        if ($(ele).hasClass("color")) {
            $(ele).animate({opacity: 0.5}, 500).removeClass("color");

            if (i < (length - 1)) {

                $(items[i + 1]).animate({opacity: 1}, 500).addClass("color");

            }
            else {
                $(items[0]).animate({opacity: 1}, 500).addClass("color");
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
}

function CF() {
    intervalId = setInterval(function() {
        loopy();
    }, 4000);
}
$('.content').mouseenter(function() {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
    $('.color').removeClass('color');
    $(this).addClass('color');
}).mouseleave(function() {
    CF();
});

CF();
```

**[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manoj_admlab/hL2qU/2/)**

Comment: yes, that stops the function but now I've run into further problems. When mouse enters I want to remove the "color" class from whatever div  has it and add it to the div that I am hovering over. How would I be able to do that?